# List items width 50% but have margin take out of their width

Tags: html, css

Might be a simple question but I have this layout here

[image]

so basically what it is, is a `ul` with with the `display` set to `flex` and `flex-wrap` set to `wrap` and inside are `li` with there `width` set to `50%` so we get two `li` together before it wraps.. now I want to have space between each list item about 10px on either side.. so whats happening is this

[image]

so obiously each list item is wrapping because the margin is added on top of the 50% width... is there a way I can still have a margin around each item but it just takes away from the width of the `li` item? so I get this layout..

[image]

my code is as follows

**html**

```
<ul class="role-select__selection">
  <li>BUSINESS OWNER</li>
  <li>FINANCE TEAM</li>
  <li>BOOK KEEPER</li>
  <li>ACCOUNTANT</li>
  <li>OTHER</li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
.role-select__selection{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.role-select__selection li{
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 3px;
    font-size: 0.70em;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    padding: 8px 8px;
}
```

any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use CSS `calc` for that.

```css
.role-select__selection{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.role-select__selection li{
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 3px;
    font-size: 0.70em;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    padding: 8px 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="role-select__selection">
  <li>BUSINESS OWNER</li>
  <li>FINANCE TEAM</li>
  <li>BOOK KEEPER</li>
  <li>ACCOUNTANT</li>
  <li>OTHER</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a slightly simpler way of setting the exact width and height gap between the individual `li` boxes, you could also use `display: grid;`. Here's my approach:

```css
.role-select__selection{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    column-gap: 1rem;
    row-gap: 1rem;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.role-select__selection li{
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 3px;
    font-size: 0.70em;
    padding: 8px 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="role-select__selection">
  <li>BUSINESS OWNER</li>
  <li>FINANCE TEAM</li>
  <li>BOOK KEEPER</li>
  <li>ACCOUNTANT</li>
  <li>OTHER</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you **must** support IE11, than you must use some `-ms` prefix. in my opinion, it's god enough nowadays: https://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Comment: and what if you support cross-browser?

Comment: As you can see in my link before, there is full support in: Edge 16+, Firefox 59+, Chrome 64+, Safari 11+, iOS Safari 10.3+, Chrome for Android 66+, UC Browser for Android 11.8, Samsung Internet 6.2+

Comment: grid-row-gap is Deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row-gap

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my solution to `row-gap` and `column-gap`. For IE, you're right. IE11 does not support `gap`s. But who uses IE11? ;)

Comment: some poor people :)